# Bitwise Majority function between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement an efficient bitwise [majority function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) between columns of a dataframe.

To make things simple, I am showing a transposed column below (columns are 0,1,2,3 and one particular row A).

```
         A      
      +-----+
   0  | 000 |
      +-----+
   1  | 111 |
      +-----+
   2  | 001 |
      +-----+
   3  | 001 |
      +-----+

      +-----+
Output| 001 |
      +-----+
```

The calculation is done by finding the most repeated bit value in each position. For example, the LSB values are [0,1,1,1] so the returned LSB is 1. Similarly the other two bits are calculated to be 0 and 0.

What is the best way to compute this majority function? Does the method to calculate the majority differ if the values are stored as integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second edit: It is actually easier if you do not split the digits into a list, but to access the i-th character of a string via `df.str.get()`:

```
df.T.apply(lambda row: ''.join([str(int(row.str.get(i).astype(int).mean() >= 0.5)) for i in range(3)]))
```

If you have your numbers as integers instead of strings, you just have to replace the method to extract the i-th digit:

```
n_digits = 3
df.T.apply(lambda row: ''.join([str(int(((row // 2**i) % 2).mean() >= 0.5)) for i in range(n_digits-1, -1, -1)]))
```

Old answer:
Convert each entry to a list of integers, check if the mean is at least 0.5, and join the resulting list of Boolean values back to a string of zeros and ones.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['000','111','001','001'],['111','111','101','001']], columns=['0','1','2','3'], index=['A','B'])

(df.T.apply(lambda row: 
           (row.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).astype(int).mean() >= 0.5)
           .astype(int))
 .astype(str)
 .apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)))
```

Edit: Let's have a closer look at the code from the inside out: The variable `x` is the binary representation of a number as a string. It first gets transformed to a list of single characters, then to a Series of single characters, and then to a Series of integers:

```
x = '001'
print(list(x))
print(pd.Series(list(x)))
print(pd.Series(list(x)).astype(int))
>>>
['0', '0', '1']
0    0
1    0
2    1
dtype: object
0    0
1    0
2    1
dtype: int32
```

We use this transformation for a whole row (which is a column of `df.T`, remember that `apply` works on columns by default):

```
row = df.loc['A']
print(row.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).astype(int))
>>>
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  1
```

Next comes the majority function: The i-th digit should be 1 if at least 50% of the entries of a column are 1. We can check this by computing the mean of the i-th column and comparing it to 0.5:

```
print(df.T.apply(lambda row: row.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).astype(int).mean() >=0.5))
>>>
       A     B
0  False  True
1  False  True
2   True  True
```

The rest of the code converts each column, which is basically a list of Boolean values, back to a list of integers, then to a list of strings, and finally to a single string, so `[False, False, True]` becomes `[0, 0, 1]`, which becomes `['0', '0', '1']`, which is joined to `'001'`.

Comment: This definitely works as far as a few examples that I tried out. Could you explain what your code does? Also, all my entries are integers (which can be represented by 8bits). I showed the binary representation to be clear in explaining my intention.